# 'XML' document with multiple root elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an 'XML' file, which I do not control, which I am trying to parse with `etree.ElementTree`  which contains two root elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<meta>
    ... data I do not care about
</meta>

<database>
    ... data I wish to parse
</database>
```

Trying to parse the file I'm getting the error: '`junk after document element'` which I understand is related to the fact that it isn't valid xml, since xml can only have one root element. I've been reading around for a solution, and while I have found a few posts addressing this issue they have all been different enough or difficult enough that I could not, as a beginner, get my head round them.

As I understand it the solution would either be to encase everything in a new root element, and parse that, or somehow ignore/split off the `<meta>` element and it's children. Any guidance on how to best accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: The solutions are either put them both in one root or split them into two files. And then stab whoever gave you that file.

Comment: Can you use `BeautifulSoup`? `bs` will parse this xml no problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - That much I knew already - see my question (well I hadn't considered it as a stabbable offence). What I'm not sure is how best to accomplish it. Specifically I would like to do so without writing a new file to disk.

Comment: @AndrejKesely There's no reason I can't. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Use a file-like that starts at the second document and pass that to the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful Soup might ease your problem (although it is the lxml inside which renders this service), but its a long-term downgrade, thus for instance when you want to use xpath.

Stick to ET. It is strict and won't allow you to parse not well-formed XML, which requires one root element and nothing else outside of it.

If you manage to parse your xml-file, you can be sure, it is well-formed. All options are legit:

1) Read the file as a string, remove the declaration and put the root tags around it. Then parse from string. (Clear the string variable after that.) Or you could edit the file first.

2) Create a new root element ( new_root = ET.Element('new_root') ), read the top-level elements in the file an append them with SubElement.

The second option requires more coding and maintainance, if the file gets changed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution using `BeautifulSoup`, in `data` is malformed xml. BeautifulSoup will process it as any document, so you can access both parts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<meta>
    <somedata>1</somedata>
</meta>

<database>
    <important>100</important>
</database>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.database.important.text)
```

Prints:

```
100
```